# How to control buttons wih jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new with jquery but I will try to explain my problem the best I can, this is my problem: I have one input, i will write one random question inside it for example- How old are you? I have 2 buttons the first one says: Put above and the second one is put below ... now I already have 2 questions and one checkbox with each question, if I write on the input and click the first button that question will be the first question "it will be above the other ones (it will include the checkbox)" and if I click the second button it will be below the other ones "it will include the checkbox"

The question is, how can I do that, I need to save all the row? or how
Here is my source code, it's all that I have at this moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/file2.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="id" class="mi_clase">
<input type="text" id="pregunta">
<button id="arriba" type="button">Poner arriba</button>
<button id="abajo" type="button">Poner abajo</button>
    <table><tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Te gusta el cine?</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
    <td id="eliminar">Eliminar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Te gusta los tacos?</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2"/></td> 
    <td id="eliminar">Eliminar</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <button id="guardar" type="button">Guardar</button>     
</div>
<div class="mi_clase">


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#guardar").click(function() {
var seleccionados = $.makeArray($(':checkbox').map(function(i, item) {
    if($(item).is(':checked'))
    return parseInt($(item).val());
}));

console.log(seleccionados);
});

$("#eliminar").click(function(){

});

$("#arriba").click(function(){
    var p = $("#pregunta").val();
    console.log(p);
    var td1 = $("<td></td>").text(p);
    var td2 = $("<td><input type='checkbox' value='2' /></td>");
    var td3 = $("<td></td>");
if(p != ""){

}
});

$("#abajo").click(function(){

if($("#pregunta").val() !=""){
$("tbody").append();
}
});

});
```

Comment: ooops, you pasted the html twice

Comment: is it possible to convert the text in your code to English?

Comment: I edited it and sure gurvinder372 poner arriba = put above, poner abajo = put below, eliminar = delete and the question on the left of delete it can by any question

Comment: The first thing, <buttons>push me</button>, without a type attribute, defaults to a submit button in some browsers.  Add type = 'button' to each of your buttons.

Comment: nice information, I already edited the post

Comment: What are you trying to put your text above/below in your html structure?  And what are  you planning to do with the array you created?

Comment: yes I want to do exactly that and about the array I want to see if it's checked, erase the question when you click save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest 2 things?
1.Put a visual to understand what do you want
2.Never Name selectors or variables on gibberish based :)

From what I'v understood that you need to delete rows based on checkbox marked, Right?
If so.. its quit simple I made this codepen for you:

EDIT1: 
http://codepen.io/Mohamedamin/pen/vLJQEE

```
$('#down').on('click', function(){
  var question = $('#pregunta').val()
  $('.stuff').append(makeRow(question));
});
$('#up').on('click', function(){
  var question = $('#pregunta').val()
  $('.stuff').prepend(makeRow(question));
});

$('#save').on('click',function(){
   var checked = $('input:checked').closest('tr')
   console.log(checked)
});
function makeRow(question){
  var row = '<tr>' +
         '<td>' + question +'</td>' +
         '<td><input type="checkbox"/></td> ' +
         '</tr>'
  return row;
};
```

Comment: this is the other problem, I have one input, i will write one random question inside it for example- How old are you? I have 2 buttons the first one says: Put above and the second one is put below ... now I already have 2 questions and one checkbox with each question, if I write on the input and click the first button that question will be the first question "it will be above the other ones (it will include the checkbox)" and if I click the second button it will be below the other ones "it will include the checkbox"

Comment: @JorgeAlberto
Man, at least translate the stuff :) 
Anyway so you will add the rows dynamically and every row will have checkbox in it? then you want to delete those selected rows ?
Correct me if I am wrong so I will do a working example once :)

Comment: Yes you're correct if I write inside the input a question like, how are you? it will add as the first question or the last question it depends if you click first or second button, "it will have checkbox as the other ones" and at the bottom I have the button guardar, that's "save", to save the questions that I have at that moment, any help is welcome

Comment: @JorgeAlberto here u go.

Answer (score 1):

Still  not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  I wrote some code that,   After inserting  the first row, with will prepend or append after the selected row. A radio button is used to select the target row.  The radio button is also   used targeting the row for the delete.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#guardar").click(function () {
                    $(":radio:checked").closest("tr").remove();
                });

                $("#arriba").click(function () {
                    var p = $("#pregunta").val();
                    if (p.length > 0) {
                        var $tr = createRow(p);
                        // first added row, just put it at the bottom
                        if ($(":radio").length == 0) {
                            // no rows added yet
                            $("table tbody").append($tr);
                        }
                        else {
                            if($(":radio:checked").length == 0){
                                // rows added but now rows selected so put it first.
                                $($(":radio")[0]).closest("tr").before($tr);
                            }
                            else{
                                $(":radio:checked").closest("tr").before($tr);
                            }
                        }
                        $("#pregunta").val("");
                    }
                });

                $("#abajo").click(function () {
                    var p = $("#pregunta").val();
                    if (p.length > 0) {
                        var $tr = createRow(p);
                           // first added row, just put it at the bottom
                        if ($(":radio").length == 0 || $(":radio:checked").length == 0) {
                            // no rows added yet
                            $("table tbody").append($tr);
                        }
                        else {
                            $(":radio:checked").closest("tr").after($tr);
                        }
                        $("#pregunta").val("");
                    }
                });

            });
            function createRow(p) {
                var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
                $tr.append("<td>" + p + "</td>")
                $tr.append("<td><input type='radio' name='rdo' value='2' /></td>");
                $tr.append("<td></td>");
                return $tr;
            }
        </script>
```

and

```
     <form name="form" action="action.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()">
            <div id="id" class="mi_clase">
                <input type="text" id="pregunta">
                <button type="button" id="arriba">Put Above</button>
                <button type="button" id="abajo">Put Below</button>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Te gusta el cine?</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
                            <td id="eliminar">Delete</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Te gusta los tacos?</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" value="2" /></td>
                            <td id="eliminar">Delete</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="button" id="guardar">Guardar</button>
            </div>
            <div class="mi_clase"></div>
    </form>
```