# How to use tables with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new with jquery but I will try to explain my problem the best I can, this is my problem:
I have one input, i will write one random question inside it for example- How old are you? I have 2 buttons the first one says: Put above and the second one is put below ... now I already have 2 questions and one checkbox with each question, if I write on the input and click the first button that question will be the first question "it will be above the other ones (it will include the checkbox)" and if I click the second button it will be below the other ones "it will include the checkbox"

The question is, how can I do that, I need to save all the row? or how

Here is my source code

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="file2.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="id" class="mi_clase">
        <input type="text" id="pregunta">
        <button id="arriba" type="button">Poner arriba</button>
        <button id="abajo" type="button">Poner abajo</button>
        <a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar Fila</a>
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Te gusta el cine?</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Te gusta los tacos?</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id="guardar" type="button">Guardar</button>     
    </div>
    <div class="mi_clase">
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#guardar").click(function() {
        var seleccionados = $.makeArray($(':checkbox').map(function(i, item) {
            if ($(item).is(':checked'))
                return parseInt($(item).val());
        }));

        console.log(seleccionados);
    });

    $('.delete').on('click', function() {
        $('.table input:checked').closest('tr').hide()
    });

    $("#arriba").click(function() {
        var p = $("#pregunta").val();
        console.log(p);
        var td1 = $("<td></td>").text(p);
        var td2 = $("<td><input type='checkbox' value='2' /></td>");
        var td3 = $("<td></td>");
        if (p != "") {

        }
    });

    $("#abajo").click(function() {

        if ($("#pregunta").val() != "") {
            $("tbody").append();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Seems like you forgot to write a question. You wrote requirements, not a question.

Comment: `And here is my js` - you're going to get this working one question at a time, right - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782439/how-to-control-buttons-wih-jquery - welcome to the world of full stack overflow programming

Comment: I edited it, I forgot the question, I'm sick and can't think clearly, thanks for your help, any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `append/prepend` new row you could use the following code. See the comments in the code. Finally use `append` to add the new row as the last row or `prepend` to add the new as the very first row. HTH

```
function createNewRow(){
    var p = $("#pregunta").val();

    // create the new elements first
    var $tr = $("<tr>");
    var $td1 = $("<td>");
    var $td2 = $("<td>");
    var $input = $("<input>", {"type": "checkbox", "value": "2"});

    // append text to cell 1
    $td1.append(p);

    // append input to cell 2
    $td2.append($input);

    // append cells 1 and 2 to new row              
    $tr.append($td1);
    $tr.append($td2);

    return $tr;
}

// get body and prepend row to body
$("#arriba").click(function() {
    var $tr = createNewRow();
    var $tableBody = $(".table tbody");
    $tableBody.prepend($tr);
});

// get body and append row to body
$("#abajo").click(function() {
    var $tr = createNewRow();
    var $tableBody = $(".table tbody");
    $tableBody.append($tr);
});
```

Or in short form like this:

```
$(".table tbody").prepend(createNewRow());
```

Comment: So I need to copy all of that except $tableBody.append($tr); "if I want to put it  on prepend? for example"

Comment: That's all that I want, very nice information and explanation of how to do it, thx

Comment: I am glad it help and wish you a speedy recovery :).